# According to the triune concept, at what point does this logically structured statement become NOT True?

Tags: trinity, monotheism

## According to the concept of the Trinity, where does this logic fail?

1. There is One True God, YHWH
2. The God of Abraham, Isaac, and Jacob is YHWH.
3. Jesus declares the 1 God to be the God of Abraham, Isaac, and Jacob.
4. Jesus declares the 1 God to be his Father.
5. Therefore the Father is the One True God YHWH.
6. Jesus cannot be the One True God YHWH.

***YHWH says He is rational and able to be understood.***

Jer 9

> 23 Thus says **YHWH**:
> “Let not the wise glory in his wisdom,
> Let not the mighty glory in his might,
> Nor let the rich glory in his riches;
> 24 But let him who glories glory in this,
> That he ***understands and knows Me***,
> That I am **YHWH**, exercising lovingkindness, judgment, and righteousness in the earth.
> For in these I delight,” says **YHWH**.

---

*Jesus answered him, “The **first** of all the commandments is: ‘Hear, O Israel, YHWH our Elohim, **YHWH is 1**.  And you shall love YHWH your Elohim with all your heart, with all your soul, with all your mind, and with all your strength.’ This is the first commandment."*

Luke 4:18 (Jesus reads from a **scroll** in the synagogue.)

> "The Spirit of the **YHWH** is upon me, because he hath anointed me to preach the gospel to the poor; he hath sent me to heal the brokenhearted, to preach deliverance to the captives, and recovering of sight to the blind, to set at liberty them that are bruised,"

Psalm 84:2

> My soul longs, yes, even faints For the courts of **YHWH**; My heart and my flesh cry out for ***the living God***.

Matthew 16:16

> Simon Peter answered and said, “You are the Christ, the ***Son of the living God***.”

Acts 3:13

> **The God of Abraham, Isaac, and Jacob**, the God of our fathers, glorified **His Servant Jesus**, whom you delivered up and denied in the presence of Pilate, when he was determined to let Him go.

Matthew 22

> 43 He said to them, “How then does David in the Spirit call Him ‘Lord,’ saying:
>
> 44 **‘YHWH said to my Lord**,
>
> “Sit at My right hand,
>
> Till I make Your enemies Your footstool” ’?

Mark 12:25-27(Jesus speaking to the pharisees, quoting scripture)

> **‘I am the God of Abraham, the God of Isaac, and the God of Jacob’**? 27 He is not the God of the dead, but the God of the living. You are therefore greatly mistaken.”

John 17:3 (Jesus speaking to his God and Father)

> And this is eternal life, that they may know **You, the only true God**, and Jesus Christ whom You have sent.

John 20:17

> Jesus said to her, “Do not cling to Me, for I have not yet ascended to My Father; but go to My brethren and say to them, **‘I am ascending to My Father and your Father, and to My God and your God.’** ”

Comment: What scripture supports point 3?

Comment: My answer is the The Shema which is 100% sufficient.  But there are others.

Comment: But in exactly which scripture did "Jesus **declare** his God to be …"?

Comment: Mark 12
" 29And Jesus answered him, The first of all the commandments is, Hear, O Israel; YHWH elohim is ONE Lord: 30And thou shalt love YHWH your elohim with all thy heart, and with all thy soul, and with all thy mind, and with all thy strength: this is the first commandment."
Only the son declares Him.  John 17:3.  Jesus doesn't contradict of hide simple truths of the Father to babes.

Comment: Luke 4:18 "The Spirit of the YHWH is upon me, because he hath anointed me to preach the gospel to the poor; he hath sent me to heal the brokenhearted, to preach deliverance to the captives, and recovering of sight to the blind, to set at liberty them that are bruised,"

Comment: Matt22:43 He saith unto them, How then doth David in spirit call him Lord, saying,

44 "YHWH said unto my Lord, Sit thou on my right hand, till I make thine enemies thy footstool"?   We see here Jesus is making himself distinct from YHWH.

Comment: In Mark 12 Jesus does not say anything about "**his** God" as point 3 claims. — In Luke 4:18, the Greek word is "kyrios", not "JHWH". — In Matthew 22:43, the Hebrew word is "'āḏôn", not "YHWH". — So for the fourth time, in what scripture can point 3 be found, where Jesus says that YHWH is **his** god?

Comment: Right.... It was translated into greek by someone later.  Jesus was reading a scroll.

Comment: Why are you commenting?  Just formulate an answer and we can discuss it.

Comment: "*Just formulate an answer and we can discuss it*".  My answer would be that the logic looks fine.  However, I believe that what's postulated is unsupported (specifically point 3, which claims that Jesus explicitly said that **YHWH** was **his** God).

Comment: @RayButterworth Fair enough.  Doesn't that sound like a good answer?  I think so...

Comment: "*Are we to conclude, then that the triune concept defies logic?*", from a Catholic perspective, the answer is definitely "yes". The Trinity Doctrine is referred to as a *mystery*, where "*a mystery is a truth which we are not merely incapable of discovering apart from Divine Revelation, but which, even when revealed, remains 'hidden by the veil of faith and enveloped, so to speak, by a kind of darkness'*". — [CATHOLIC ENCYCLOPEDIA: The Blessed Trinity](https://www.newadvent.org/cathen/15047a.htm#iv)

Comment: @ReadLessPrayMore the point of this site is general discussion of Christianity interpreted broadly but with this question you seem more bent on convincing others of your specific interpretation thereof, which would be off-topic.

Comment: Jesus said, "Jesus answered, “The most important is, ‘Hear, O Israel: The Lord our God, **the Lord** is one." Your doctrine replaces the written Word of God with something you believe was spoken. Then you must ignore the plain reading of Scripture, "yet for us there is one God, the Father, from whom are all things and for whom we exist, and one Lord, Jesus Christ, through whom are all things and through whom we exist." (1 Corinthians 8:6). If Israel has one Lord, it can only be Jesus Christ.

Comment: @RayButterworth.  John 20:17

Comment: @User14, If that short answer was in response to either of these:
"*in what scripture can point 3 be found, where Jesus says that YHWH is his god?*", and
"*in exactly which scripture did "Jesus declare his God to be the God of Abraham, Isaac, and Jacob?*", it really doesn't answer the question.
In John 20:17, Jesus says that the Father is his God, he does not say that YHWH is his God, and he doesn't say that the Father was the god of Abraham etc.
But if that's not what you meant, then what did that comment mean?

Comment: @RayButterworth the Father is The God of Jesus.  Is it your contention that YHWH is not the Father?

Comment: @User14, yes.  Many denominations believe that YHWH, who interacted with people in the Hebrew scriptures, was the pre-incarnate Jesus. Jesus said that mankind didn't know the Father, that he was here to reveal him. Many people saw YHWH, and many more saw Jesus, but no one has seen the Father. ¶ For point 3, YHWH, not the Father, was the god of Isaac, et al.

Comment: @RayButterworth If Jesus is YHWH, then who is YHWH's god?  This is the crux of the fallacy within your theology.  Jesus is crying out to his God on the cross.  He is begging to have the cup passed but obeys his God's will to death.   Who is the Risen Son's God?  Rev 3:12.  All this and he also tells you who his God is several times.. And yet somehow many people still want Jesus to be their god....

Comment: @ReadLessPrayMore says "*Jesus is crying out to his God on the cross.*". Right. At this time, Jesus is fully human, without the divine powers he had when he appeared as YHWH, is the Son, calling out to God the Father. Jesus knows that he is about to have the full weight of all the sins of mankind dumped on him, and as a human he really *doesn't* want to experience that pain. But he does it because that's what he came here to do.

Comment: Who is YHVH's God? Read Hebrews 1:8. Just as Jesus calls His Father God, the Father calls Jesus God. "I and the Father are one." The text is straightforward and unambiguous.

Comment: The Father has no god because there is 1 Father OVER ALL.  God is rational according to His own words.....Jer 9:23-24....Who is asserting a mystery here about our God and Father?  They deny His own words.

Comment: @RayButterworth Regarding point 3: Acts 3:13

"The God of Abraham, Isaac, and Jacob, the God of our fathers, glorified His Servant Jesus, whom you delivered up and denied in the presence of Pilate, when he was determined to let Him go.">>> Yes not Jesus' words.  Is that okay?  Do you deny this scripture?

Comment: @ReadLessPrayMore, the question explicitly asks for a Trinitarian perspective, but the argument presented is that of a unitarian. From a Trinitarian view, "Jesus is the one true God" and "The Father is the one true God" is not a contradiction, so the question itself doesn't make sense.

Comment: Logic is not exclusive to one Theology.  It can be applied to any concept or theory or idea.

Comment: @Raybutterworth You just said 2 people were the 1 True God. 
 But can you find me an example in language where 1 person is calling another person the ONLY of some type, yet that person speaking is ALSO this ONLY of the same type?  This is not a unitarian perspective.  Its a logical perspective.  Logic is not exclusive to one Theology. It can be applied to any concept or theory or idea.

Comment: @ReadLessPrayMore says "*Logic is not exclusive to one Theology. It can be applied to any concept or theory or idea.*".  True.  I wasn't faulting the logic. ¶ "*find me an example in language where 1 person is calling another person the ONLY of some type, yet that person speaking is ALSO this ONLY of the same type?*". In Catholic theology, the Father and the Son are separate persons, but they are also the same one God. Suppose you are a teacher and your daughter is in your class. Depending upon the situation, she will refer to you as "Dad" or as "Mr. More", but you are the same being.

Comment: @RayButterworth One being yet 2 persons?  How many personalities does YHWH have?  I've tried in vain to get an explanation of the ontology of the trinity substance.  How is a being different than a person?  Can you point to another single being who uses singular pronouns but who is also 2 persons?

Comment: @ReadLessPrayMore asks "*One being yet 2 persons? How many personalities does YHWH have?*". In this case, 3, or at least that's what the Trinitarian viewpoint that you asked for would say. I'm only reporting it, not defending it.  ¶ You could read [CATHOLIC ENCYCLOPEDIA: The Blessed Trinity — a mystery](https://www.newadvent.org/cathen/15047a.htm#iv) for a full description of the Catholic doctrine.

Answer (score 8):

The logic fails at step 6 because the logician fails to understand the Trinitarian Christology [defined at Chalcedon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chalcedonian_Definition) (AD 451) that the flesh and blood fully human Jesus is the same being as the [Nicean God the Son](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicene_Creed) (the second person of the Trinity): same being having two natures (fully human and fully divine) commingling in one hypostasis (the [hypostatic union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypostatic_union)).

Once the logician comprehends that when God the Son (the 2nd person of the Trinity) was conceived in the virgin womb of Mary, a new (human) nature was **added to the preexisting divine being**, the YHWH testified by the OT, who created heavens and earth in Genesis, who already existed "before" the universe.  This divine being YHWH **joined** His creation in solidarity with humanity by **also** becoming one of us (as the human Jesus) without losing all His divine attributes.  This is the miracle of incarnation.
(I put "before" in double quotes because time itself "was" created along with space and matter.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140019/discussion-between-gratefuldisciple-and-read-less-pray-more).

Comment: " a new (human) nature was added to the preexisting divine being, the YHWH testified by the OT".... ok...So I guess YHWH changes according to the trinity doctrine...For I YHWH do not change; therefore you, O children of Jacob, are not consumed. (Malachi 3:6)

Comment: @ReadLessPrayMore I'm answering in the [designated chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140019/discussion-between-gratefuldisciple-and-read-less-pray-more) for this answer.

Answer (score 4):

I have taken notice that when asked to back up various of the logical "steps" in the question OP has referred to the "Shema" from Deuteronomy 6 (and also quoted by Jesus).  Below the logical progression OP has written:  "“The first of all the commandments is: ‘Hear, O Israel, YHWH our Elohim, YHWH is 1".

The problem lies not in the logical structure of the statement but in an underlying assumption that *echad*, here in Deuteronomy 6, represents the [cardinal rather than the ordinal number](https://www.editarians.com/cardinals-ordinals/).  This is not necessarily the case.  While it may be translated as an cardinal number (Gen. 2:21, Gen. 4:19, for example) it is also, very often, translated as an ordinal number demonstrating "first" rather than "1" (Gen. 1:5, Gen. 8:5, for example).

There is also a take on this word *echad* which applies heavily to its primitive root *achad* which signifies unification and which is differentiated from another derivation of that same root *yachid* which means single.  If "yachid" and "echad" both derive from the same root and "yachid" means single then "echad" is likely to indicate something other than single:

> The key for both Jews and Christians to learn the correct concept of our God is the word echad. Echad is the Hebrew word for one, but more precisely it means a single entity but made up of more than one part.  There is another Hebrew word from the same root – Yachid which means single. The meaning of Echad (more than one part) is a confirmation of the Hebrew word Elohim which is translated as God. Elohim is a plural word – more than one being called God - [Kehila News](https://news.kehila.org/the-meaning-of-the-word-echad-one/)

However, this nuance of a single united plurality need not be the case in order to answer the logic problem.  If *echad* is ordinal in the "Shema" rather than cardinal then the greatest commandment is a statement of primacy rather than number.  This resonates as verse 5, then, is an expansion and application of the truth proclaimed in verse 4 which is that God is first:

> v.4 Hear, O Israel: The LORD our God is one (**First or Primary**) LORD: v.5 And thou shalt love the LORD thy God with **all** thine heart, and with **all** thy soul, and with **all** thy might.

Comment: Similarly [Exodus 20](https://www.blueletterbible.org/kjv/exo/20/3/s_70003) says "*I am the LORD thy God … . Thou shalt have no other gods before me.*". That is, he's the number 1 god, not necessarily the only god there is.

Comment: @RayButterworth The "me" in "Thou shalt have no other gods before me," is _singular_ (first-person common singular pronominal suffix in Hebrew).  Therefore, the commandment enjoins us to worship a singular deity.  There is no option here for plural gods, whether that be two, three, or more.

Comment: @Biblasia, yes, "me" is singular, and refers to YHWH. Yes, the commandment is to worship only YHWH. But it doesn't say that other gods don't exist. (And in the Greek scriptures, Satan is referred to as a god, so for Christians at least, there *do* exist other gods, which one is not supposed to worship.)

Comment: YHWH is 1 AND He is the 1st and ONLY.  YHWH is the Living  God and the Father of Jesus according to scripture.

Comment: @RayButterworth The context of my statement was that there is no option in the commandment for the _worship_ of plural gods.  I'm sorry that was not clear.  There would be no need for the commandment at all if other "gods" were not in existence.

Comment: @Biblasia The "me" is *pā·nā·ya" which properly means face or presence.  It refers to a single deity more than it speaks to the number of "persons" in that deity.  The worship of plural gods is very different than the worship of a single God who is plural.  The commandment forbids the former.

Comment: This is a well-written discussion of *echad*, +1

Comment: @MikeBorden What is the difference?  The commandment makes no distinction.

Comment: @ReadLessPrayMore Perhaps it does.

Comment: This answer attempts to redefine echad to be something not found anywhere else in scripture.  Echad is ALWAYS the quantity 1.  Yes... even man and woman becoming literally 1 flesh.  Its called intercourse. And the evening and the morning were 1 day.

Comment: @ReadLessPrayMore "In its first appearance in the Bible echad is an ordinal number and means "first": And there was evening and there was morning, the first day [yom echad]." - Hebrew Streams

Comment: ...."was one day".

Comment: @ReadLessPrayMore Exodus 24:3 - "And Moses came and told the people all the words of the LORD, and all the judgments: and all the people answered with **one voice**, and said, All the words that the Lord has spoken we will do."  Echad Kole.  One voice but there were many, many voices.  In unity.

Comment: Figuratively 1 voice.  Which is why I've asked in vain here many times for the ontology of the trinity?  What is a being and how is this different than a person?   How can 2 persons figuratively be 1 being?  No one knows because no one is willing to define words.  My ontology question was hated by the majority here and then singlehandedly deleted forever by 1 mod.

Comment: @ReadLessPrayMore So you admit that Echad has a figurative meaning?  The word Echad, (from it's primitive root) properly conveys unity:  Evening and morning, light and darkness unite to make 1 day.  When Jesus said that he and the Father were one don't you suppose he had the Shema ringing in his hears, also those who heard him?  If you'd like to go into a chat I would be happy to talk about ontology.

Comment: Writing in general can be figurative.  The words mean what they mean.  Echad means quantity 1 and it can be used figurative writing if the author pleases just like any other word.

Comment: John 10:30-33 The Jews certainly understood Jesus to be referencing the Shema and he used a Greek word that can be either cardinal 1 or mean unity.  Do you think he was saying that he and the Father were 1?

Comment: @MikeBorden Zephaniah 3:17
YHWH your God in your midst,
**The Mighty One**, will save;
**He** will rejoice over you with gladness,
**He** will quiet you with His love,
**He** will rejoice over you with singing.”>>>>I think Jesus was saying that he and the Father share the same Spirit...1 in Sprit.  Spiritual things.  Jesus says we are to be one in the exact same way.

Comment: In your midst (from BDB): 1) midst, among, inner part, middle
1a) inward part
1a1) physical sense
1a2) as seat of thought and emotion
1a3) as faculty of thought and emotion
1b) in the midst, among, from among (of a number of persons)
1c) entrails (of sacrificial animals)

Answer (score 2):

You present a logical conundrum, asking where (according to trinitarianism) the logic fails, and many answers dealt with that directly.  However, now a bounty has been placed on the Q. as the OP is "looking for a canonical answer". I'm inclined to think the goalposts have just been moved wider apart, but will reserve comment on that until after you have explained - exactly - what you mean by a "canonical" answer. Do you mean answers contained within the canon of scripture? Some of the answers also quote scripture, as well as looking at the logic.

If you want scriptures that show the conclusion (Jesus cannot be the One True God, YHWH) to be illogical or unwarranted, then I will answer.

**My answer points to** John 8:58 as one statement of Jesus that flags up the flaw in logic Point 3. There are others.

**My answer points to** John 5:39-40 as one statement of Jesus that flags up the flaw in logic Point 4. There are others.

If the errors in Points 3 & 4 are not sorted out, then Points 5 & 6 would appear to be logical follow-ons. But if ***Points 3 & 4 can be shown from scripture to be flawed*** (and they can), then the conclusion is wrong.  However, I'm not going to spend a lot of time on this as it could transpire that the Q. is altered once more. There comes a time when, if the OP does not receive an answer satisfactory to the given claims in the Q, a fresh Q needs to be posted, I would suggest.

Comment: Indeed, and as Ray pointed out in comments on the question, the assertion that Jesus claims YHWH to be *His* God needs to be substantiated. Certainly, Jesus claims YHWH to be *the* God. But He can do that, while *being Himself* that same God, without inconsistency.

Comment: @Matthew John 20:17?

Comment: -1 This comes across with a decidedly unbecoming and ungracious attitude, and rather comes short of answering the question.  As the old saying goes, if a job is worth doing, it's worth doing right.  If you take the time to propose an answer, make it relevant to all readers here, not merely to the OP.  Instead of "My answer points to...," include the actual passage so that it is easy for readers to see what you are referencing.  Most of this "answer" is more suitable as a comment, except that it is too lengthy for even that.  A proper answer it is not.

Comment: @Matthew Where does Jesus claim YHWH to be _the_ God?

Comment: @Biblasia, Mark 12:29? Or that He didn't contradict any of the many, many OT monotheistic assertions?

Comment: @Matthew If Mark 12:29, and I tend to agree, supports that Jesus accepted YHWH to be the true God, then you have also made an answer to Ray Butterworth's question: "What scripture supports point 3?"  This is because of John 20:17, John 17:3, and John 4:21-23.

Comment: Please know that whenever I ask a question here on this "Christianity" site, I will ALWAYS be searching for an answer that is based on what the Spirit of Truth reveals directly through the scriptures.  Jesus is our only teacher.

Comment: @Matthew Acts 3:13

*The God of Abraham, Isaac, and Jacob, the God of our fathers, glorified **His Servant Jesus**, whom you delivered up and denied in the presence of Pilate, when he was determined to let Him go.*>>>> Jesus is a servant of the God of Abraham, Isaac and Jacob... He is a servant to YHWH according to this scripture.  YHWH is his God.

Comment: @ReadLessPrayMore, the Son is the *exemplar* of a servant, yes. And the Son is not the Father. The Father can glorify the Son (and vice versa) while both are still one God. If you feel there is a legitimate challenge here (I can guarantee that Trinitarians disagree), please ask a Question rather than burying it in a comment.

Comment: @Matthew I was responding to your first comment here.  A servant of YHWH can not be YHWH anymore than the son of YHWH can be YHWH.  You said this: *"But He can do that, while being Himself that same God, without inconsistency."*  Why do you think he can do this and yet tell his brethren something different.  Is he trying to hide the truth from his disciples?

Comment: Another non-answer that gets upvoted.  I'm all for pats on the back but maybe its not appropriate when a good answer is being sought out by others here.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the other answers, it can be considered not true at plenty of the points; what you have put is not enough to disclaim certain proposed logics completely, you need to include the fact that Jesus prayed to the Father in Gethsemane (Matthew 26:36–56; Mark 14:32–50; Luke 22:39–53; John 18:1–12) when he was alone (aka it was not to be an example or anything like that), which doesn't make sense if it is himself. 

Or that he said on the cross, "Father, why hast thou forsaken me?"; forsaken means *left entirely*. So now (if we believe they are two natures of the same being), he is not only *leaving himself* somehow , but also does not know *why* he is *leaving himself* .

And how about Psalm 110:1

> A Psalm of David. The Lord says to my Lord: “Sit at my right hand,
> until I make your enemies your footstool.”

Was he instructing *himself* to sit by *himself*, and telling *himself* that he will make *his own* enemies *a different part of himself*'s footstool? Besides, **if the Son is only a different part of him on earth, then why is he still addressed by God as a separate person when he's in heaven?** 
More scriptures about Jesus sitting at the Right Hand of The Father can be found [here](https://www.openbible.info/topics/jesus_sitting_at_the_right_hand_of_the_father).

We ***must*** understand that this is merely the concept of an imperfect flawed human, and pray to know for ourselves if they are separate beings or not, if we really don't think the scriptures are clear.
I love the OP's name, did you see it?

Answer (score -1):

The logic itself doesn't fail.

But the conclusion wouldn't necessarily be true if any of the individual statements aren't true.

In particular, there is no obvious support for the truth of this statement:

> 3. Jesus declares his God to be the God of Abraham, Isaac, and Jacob.

Consider what Jesus himself said:

> … Nor does anyone know the Father except the Son, and the one to whom the Son wills to reveal Him.
> — Matthew 11:27

> No one has seen God at any time. The only begotten Son, who is in the bosom of the Father, He has declared Him.
> — John 1:18

> But the hour is coming, and now is, when the true worshipers will worship the Father …
> — John 1:18

> If you had known Me, you would have known My Father also; and from now on you know Him and have seen Him.
> — John 14:7

> O righteous Father! The world has not known You, but I have known You; and these have known that You sent Me.
> And I have declared to them Your name, and will declare it, that the love with which You loved Me may be in them, and I in them.
> — John 17:25,26

Jesus says that:

- No one has known the Father.
- No one has seen the Father.
- No one has worshipped the Father.

It wasn't until Jesus revealed him to mankind that anyone ever knew of the Father's existence.

This clearly indicates that the Father *wasn't* the God of Abraham, Isaac, and Jacob, so without evidence to support it, point 3 cannot be considered true.

(One might even make a similar argument for point 1, but one false statement is enough to invalidate the conclusion given in the question.)

---

The problem with this question is that it presumes a unitarian God for one of its points and then uses it to disprove non-unitarian doctrine.

All the logic steps are correct, but the result is wrong because it assumes that the conclusion is already known to be true.
This logical fallacy is known as [*Begging the question*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begging_the_question).

Comment: Hear, O Israel: The LORD our God is one LORD.
shâma‛ yiśrâ'êl YHWH elohim 'echâd YHWH.

Read this as a babe and you too will see thee Truth of this; THEE most important commandment passed on throughout generations.

Comment: @ReadLessPrayMore, cryptic comments don't help anyone. Is that supposed to be proof that "Jesus declares his God to be the God of Abraham", or what? ¶ Or if anyone else reading this knows how this is relevant, please let me know.

Comment: Proof?  Is anything proven?  But it does strengthen it BEYOND any man made irrational doctrine.   Its his most important command for heaven's sake.  Its only cryptic to trinitarians.  My brethren see and hear.  Ears to   hear.  Can't hear when we are in the pride of our knowledge of man made doctrines..

Comment: @ReadLessPrayMore, with respect to disputing this answer, the only proof or support that's relevant is scripture that explicitly confirms point 3.  Anything else (such as proving the question's hidden agenda) is irrelevant.

Comment: @ReadLessPrayMore says "*Its only cryptic to trinitarians*".  That's good, because I'm not a trinitarian.  But in case you haven't got it yet, and I'm fairly sure you haven't, know that questions and answers on this site are supposed to be unrelated to our personal beliefs.

Comment: Yes I know.  My questions are completely rational and objective.  I am banned from questioning in the BHSE so I  am here.  These questions NEED scope.  Since the majority of users are trinitarians, that is my scope.  So much rep is up for graps within my group of questions if anyone would be brave enough to answer.

Comment: Matthew 22:43 He said to them, “How then does David in the Spirit call Him ‘Lord,’ saying:

44 ‘YHWH said to my Lord,
“Sit at My right hand,
Till I make Your enemies Your footstool” ’?_____Jesus makes a distinction here between himself and his God, YHWH.

Comment: @ReadLessPrayMore "Its only cryptic to Trinitarians" not really. It only appears that Trinitarians see it as cryptic by non-Trinitarians who don't really grasp what Trinitarians believe. Trinitarians do not have a problem with "one Lord" as stated in your cited verse.

Comment: @RayButterworth I think you have missed a couple of key teachings of Jesus that would invalidate your entire premise regarding point #3.  Here is one: _"And as touching the dead, that they rise: have ye not read in the book of Moses, how in the bush God spake unto him, saying, I am the God of Abraham, and the God of Isaac, and the God of Jacob?" (Mark 12:26, KJV)_.  See also Matthew 22:32 and Luke 20:37.  Jesus clearly taught that God is the God of Abraham, Isaac, and Jacob--and this God is identified as YHWH in the Hebrew Old Testament.

Comment: @Biblasia, agreed, YHWH was the god of Abraham. But you are equating YHWH as the Father. Many believe that YHWH was the pre-incarnate Son, not the Father, whose existence hadn't yet been revealed to humanity.

Comment: @RayButterworth But the Old Testament does identify God as our Father.

Comment: @Biblasia, it uses the analogy that YHWH is like a father, just as it uses the analogy that God is a husband to Israel. But that doesn't mean that YHWH was "The Father" that Jesus revealed. ¶ Consider: John 1:18 ("*No one has seen God at any time. [… Jesus] has declared Him.*")
John 17:25 ("*… Father! The world has not known You, but I have known You …*")
John 5:37 ("*And the Father Himself … . You have neither heard His voice at any time, nor seen His form.*").  Those statements are about "The Father" and are not true of YHWH.

Comment: @RayButterworth  Only those whose opinions are held to be more important than what the Bible actually says, and plainly so, will choose to argue that YHWH is not the true God, or that Jesus did not say that the true God is "the Father."  It's as simple as connecting the dots.  John 17:3, John 20:17, John 4:21-23--all of these tell us who God, the only true God, is--in Jesus' own words. And that is the Father. The only way for Jesus to have been wrong about the Old Testament God is for the OT to have had a _different_ God than the NT. But that conclusion would be foolish--they are the same God.

Comment: @Biblasia, I never said that "*YHWH is not the true God*", nor did I say that "*Jesus did not say that the true God is 'the Father'*".
From a trinitarian or binitarian perspective, what I said would make sense and not imply either of those statements.
Unitarians don't believe that both the Father and the Son are God, so obviously what I said wouldn't match their doctrines.
But the question asked for a Trinitarian perspective, so unitarian views are irrelevant to this question.
¶ See the explanation I added to the end of my answer.

Answer (score -1):

One failure is in the premise when Jesus says "Lord," He means YHVH:

> <sup>41</sup> Now while the Pharisees were gathered together, Jesus asked them a question, <sup>42</sup> saying, “What do you think about the Christ? Whose son is he?” They said to him, “The son of David.” <sup>43</sup> He said to them, “How is it then that David, in the Spirit, calls him Lord, saying, <sup>44</sup> “‘The Lord said to my Lord,
> “Sit at my right hand,
> until I put your enemies under your feet”’? <sup>45</sup> If then David calls him Lord, how is he his son?” 46 And no one was able to answer him a word, nor from that day did anyone dare to ask him any more questions. (Matthew 22 ESV)

The logic further fails in situations where Jesus uses "Lord" but He must be understood as not meaning YHVH:

> “Why do you call me ‘Lord, Lord,’ and not do what I tell you? (Luke 6:46)

As is evident in how the OP presents the logical progression, sometimes "Lord" must be understood as YHVH and other times as "Lord." Therefore, it is not truly a logical progression.

Comment: and how is this "according to Triune concept"?

Comment: @eques The "triune concept" as I apply it is one of consistent application of OT and NT texts. For example, the triune concept begins in Genesis 1:1 where God, is written אלהים, which is plural. Thus, any understanding of God must be consistent with this first revelation. Certainly there are other understandings of how to understand this plural/singular nature, however, given the ability of the language to use other words which are clearly singular (i.e. El Shaddai or simply El), a plural nature is the most reasonable. This particular question wrecks havoc with any **logical** approach ---

Comment: ---since it selectively replaces the actual text with something the OP believes Jesus should have, or might have said. This is not logic. However, one can respond, as I have done, by using the same "logical" method, in a manner the triune concept would. So "Lord, Lord" means "Lord YHVH." Jesus said, "why do you call me Lord YHVH and not do what I say?" Here we have a clear example of Jesus declaring Himself to be YHVH, which I am sure the OP would reject because YHVH is not in the text. But it is the same "logic" which is the foundation of the OP's question, hence, an appropriate answer.

Comment: LORD = YHWH in the OT.  Its very simple.  Jesus is quoting the OT and reading from a scroll at one point...

Comment: @ReadLessPrayMore And what is YHVH in the NT?

Comment: Do you mean WHO is YHWH in the NT?  Do you not think YHWH has a personality?  YHWH is the same throughout all scriptures and time.  He doesn't change.

Comment: @ReadLessPrayMore No. If LORD = YHVH in the OT, then LORD = YHVH in the NT as well, correct?

Comment: @RevelationLad INCORRECT. The greek word for lord is not YHWH.  The word LORD capitalized in the OT is the word YHWH which is the name HE uses for HIMSELF.